# return rss node based on date

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to return twitter titles based on today's date only. I have made the following code below, but it returns every title no matter if its today's date or not.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=google');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$twitter = $xml->xpath("//item");

foreach ($twitter as $item) {
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
    $date = new DateTime($item->pubdate);
    $date->setTimeZone($timezone);
    $twitter_date = $date->format("F j Y");
    $todays_date = date("F j Y");

    if ($twitter_date == $todays_date) {
        foreach ($twitter as $item) {
            $text = $item->title;
            echo $text.'<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping again through EVERY `$twitter` inside the `if` statement.  Try removing the `foreach` tag inside and just using the current `$item`:

```
if ($twitter_date == $todays_date) {
    $text = $item->title;
    echo $text.'<br />';
}
```